# Show a target div on audio play with a selector retrieved via a custom data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, custom-data-attribute

I have an audio player with several songs. For each song, I want to display a `div` below that has the lyrics to that specific song, while hiding the lyrics for all the other songs.

This is the script for the audio player, which works:

```
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio(element){
    var song = element.attr('song');
    var title = element.text();
    var cover = element.attr('cover');
    var artist = element.attr('artist');
    var album = element.attr('album');

    //Create audio object
    audio = new Audio('public/songs/'+ song);

    //Insert audio info
    $('.artist').text(artist);
    $('.title').text(title);
    $('.album').text(album);

    //Insert song cover
    $('img.cover').attr('src','public/images/' + cover);

    $('#playlist li').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');

    // Set timer to 0
    $('#duration').html('0:00');

    // Maintain volume on song change
    audio.volume = $('#volume').val() / 100;
}
```

And here is a simplified version of the playlist and lyrics HTML:

```
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="song-list active" song="song-1.wav" data-id="song-1"></li>
    <li class="song-list" song="song-2.wav" data-id="song-2"></li>
    <li class="song-list" song="song-3.wav" data-id="song-3"></li>
</ul>

<div id="song-1" class="lyrics">Lyrics to song 1</div>
<div id="song-2" class="lyrics">Lyrics to song 2</div>
<div id="song-3" class="lyrics">Lyrics to song 3</div>
```

I tried a lot of things, to no avail. I'm not even sure how to target each song as it plays to extract the `data-attribute`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: For the next steps we assume to target "song-1".*

1. Get the `data-id`-attribute by calling `element.attr('data-id')`;
   returns string "song-1".
2. Target the DOM element with `id="song-1"` by calling `$('#song-1')`;
   which would be `$('#' + element.attr('data-id'))` (take a look at step 1 if you don't know why).
3. Now that we have our target we should hide all other lyrics in advance `$('.lyrics').hide()` and only display the wanted one `$('#' + element.attr('data-id')).show()`.

```js
initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));

function initAudio( element ) {
    // this version performs slightly better than the one in the 1, 2, 3 explanations
    $('.lyrics').hide().filter('#' + element.attr('data-id')).show()
}

$('#playlist').on('click', function( oEvent ) {
    initAudio( $( oEvent.target ) )
} );
```

```html
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="song-list active" song="song-1.wav" data-id="song-1">Click Me 1!</li>
    <li class="song-list" song="song-2.wav" data-id="song-2">Click Me 2!</li>
    <li class="song-list" song="song-3.wav" data-id="song-3">Click Me 3!</li>
</ul>

<div id="song-1" class="lyrics">Lyrics to song 1</div>
<div id="song-2" class="lyrics">Lyrics to song 2</div>
<div id="song-3" class="lyrics">Lyrics to song 3</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works like you want it to (I hope so - at least) but isn't an ideal solution; just wanted to explain whats going on! The downside about the above solution is a lot of unnecessary computing.

So here is an advanced mockup (with less computing):

```js
//initAudio($('#playlist li:first-child'));
initAudio($('#playlist').find('li:first-child')); // performs better

function initAudio( element ) {
    // if you chain it this way you don't have to cache $('.lyrics')
    $('.lyrics') // get collection of all div.lyrics
        .filter('.active').removeClass('active') // target the current div.lyrics.active and remove class "active"
            .end() // get collection div.lyrics back again
                .filter('#' + element.attr('data-id')).addClass('active'); // filter target div.lyrics#song-[1|2|3] and add class "active"
}

$('#playlist').on('click', function( oEvent ) {
    initAudio( $( oEvent.target ) )
} );
```

```css
.lyrics { /* this will prevent to show all lyrics before you call initAudio() */
    display: none;
}
.lyrics.active { /* style active lyrics as you like */
    display: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="song-list active" song="song-1.wav" data-id="song-1">Click Me 1!</li>
    <li class="song-list" song="song-2.wav" data-id="song-2">Click Me 2!</li>
    <li class="song-list" song="song-3.wav" data-id="song-3">Click Me 3!</li>
</ul>

<!-- set one as active in advance if you like -->
<div id="song-1" class="lyrics active">Lyrics to song 1</div>
<div id="song-2" class="lyrics">Lyrics to song 2</div>
<div id="song-3" class="lyrics">Lyrics to song 3</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Additional Recommondation*

To keep valid markup while using custom HTML5 attributes simply prepend your attributes with `data-`.

So consider to change

```
song="song-#.wav"
```

to

```
data-song="song-#.wav"
```

and your markup will be valid. (The same for the other attributes as well `cover` to `data-cover`, `artist` to `data-artist`, etc.).

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-dataset

---

*References for jQuery methods that are not used in OP*

- https://api.jquery.com/filter/
- https://api.jquery.com/end/
- https://api.jquery.com/find/

---

*Additional Inspiration*

Depending on how you build your site there would be also more straight forward solutions than storing data into markup with `data-*`-attributes.

Why not separating the data from the actual HTML. For doing so you could deploy the data as a variable.

```js
var sIdCurrent = undefined,
    oData = {
    'song-1': { artist: 'artist 1', lyrics: 'Lyrics to song 1' },
    'song-2': { artist: 'artist 2', lyrics: 'Lyrics to song 2' },
    'song-3': { artist: 'artist 3', lyrics: 'Lyrics to song 3' },
};

function initAudio( sId ) {

    if ( sId === sIdCurrent ) return;
    sIdCurrent = sId;
    //$('#artist').find('span').text( oData[ sId ].artist );
    //$('#lyrics').find('span').text( oData[ sId ].lyrics );
    // the above can be abstracted to
    for ( sKey in oData[ sId ] ) {
        $('#' + sKey).find('span').text( oData[ sId ][ sKey ] );
    }

}

initAudio('song-1');

$('#playlist').on('click', function( oEvent ) {
    initAudio( oEvent.target.id )
} );
```

```html
<!-- As you can see the markup is much cleaner now.
     No need to store data uneffectively in markup. -->

<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="song-list active" id="song-1">Click Me 1!</li>
    <li class="song-list" id="song-2">Click Me 2!</li>
    <li class="song-list" id="song-3">Click Me 3!</li>
</ul>

<div id="artist">Artist: <span><span></div>
<div id="lyrics">Lyrics: <span><span></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Axel, your response was resourceful and extensive, thank you! I used the "advanced mockup" method - it works great.

I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer, but I'll be back.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Song List Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        var audio = null;

        function initAudio(songElem) 
        {
            var songID = null;
            var title = null;
            var metaID = null;
            var songFile = null;
            var cover = null;
            var artist = null;
            var album = null;

            try 
            {

                // Retrieve song Title and meta-data identifier
                songID = "#" + songElem.getAttribute("id");
                title = $(songID).text();
                metaID = "#" + $(songID).attr('data-id');

                // Get selected song data
                songFile = $(metaID).attr('song');
                cover = $(metaID).attr('cover');
                artist = $(metaID).attr('artist');
                album = $(metaID).attr('album');

                // Update summary to be displayed
                $("#currentTitle").text(title);
                $("#currentAlbum").text(album);
                $("#currentArtist").text(artist);
                $("#currentCover img").attr("src", cover);

                // Hide and display applicable song data
                $(".songmeta").hide();
                $("#currentSong").show();
                $(metaID).show();

                // Create or update audio object
                if (audio != null) audio.src = songFile;
                else audio = new Audio(songFile);

                audio.play();

                // Update current song selection
                $(".songlist").attr("active", "false");
                $(songID).attr("active", "true");

            }
            catch (e) 
            {
                alert("initAudio Error:  " + e.Message);
            }
            finally 
            {

            }

        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>

<ul id="playlist">
    <li id="s1" class="song-list" onclick="initAudio(this)" active="false" data-id="song-1">Song One</li>
    <li id="s2" class="song-list" onclick="initAudio(this)" active="false" data-id="song-2">Song Two</li>
    <li id="s3" class="song-list" onclick="initAudio(this)" active="false" data-id="song-3">Song Three</li>
</ul>

<div id="currentSong" >
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<table border="1">
<tr><td><b>Song</b></td><td id="currentTitle"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Album</b></td><td id="currentAlbum"></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Artist</b></td><td id="currentArtist"></td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td id="currentCover"><img alt="" src="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="song-1" class="songmeta" artist="Song 1 Artist" album="Song 1 Album" cover="./images/Album1.jpeg" song="./songs/Song1.mp3" >Lyrics to song 1</div>
<div id="song-2" class="songmeta" artist="Song 2 Artist" album="Song 2 Album" cover="./images/Album2.jpeg" song="./songs/Song2.mp3" >Lyrics to song 2</div>
<div id="song-3" class="songmeta" artist="Song 3 Artist" album="Song 3 Album" cover="./images/Album3.jpeg" song="./songs/Song3.mp3" >Lyrics to song 3</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // Initialization
    $(".songmeta").hide();
    $("#currentSong").hide();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is a sample that references a local copy of the jQuery library.  Keep in mind that the paths to the sound,  image, and jQuery files will need to be updated by you to reference locations on your system.  I put all the "meta data" for the songs in the "lyric" div elements.  Also, my class names are different than yours.  As for your original code, it looks like the element object passed to your function needs to have the "id" attribute retrieved (and used with the '#' prefix) prior to using the jQuery calls to get the other attribute values.  Let me know how it works.